# jQuery does absolutely nothing

Tags: jquery, performance

I am attempting to get any jquery script to work. As it currently stands, absolutely nothing happens when i put in a jquery script. I just cannot get anything to happen at all. The script src is correct. It also does nothing if i put it straight into the body. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#topwrap").slideDown("slow");
});
```

That is all i am trying to execute as im just trying to get something to happen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-- <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>NotFM</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


</head>
<body style="background-image: url(backer.jpg)">



        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser.    Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

    <div id="topwrap">          
        <div id="logo"><img src="splashimagesml.png"></div>

        <div id="radio"> <!-- This will be the radio widget --><p>RADIO WIDGET WILL GO HERE!</p></div>

        <div id="logo2"><img src="splashimagesml2.png"></div>           
    </div>    


    <div id="menubar"> <!-- This will be the menubar -->                
        <div id="wrap">     
            <a class=".top" href ="index.php?p=home">Home</a>
            <a href ="index.php?p=band">Bands</a>
            <a href ="index.php?p=gig">Gigs</a>
            <a href ="index.php?p=festival">Festivals</a>
            <a href ="index.php?p=tattoo">Tattoo</a>
            <a href ="http://www.notfm.co.uk/Forum/index.php?p=/">Forum</a>
            <a href ="index.php?p=review">Reviews</a>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="lnav"class="main"> <!-- This will be left navigation/display bar -->

            <?php
                $pages_dir = 'pages';
            if (!empty($_GET['p']))
                {                   
                $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
                unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);                    
                $p = $_GET['p'];                        
                if (in_array($p.'.php', $pages))
                     {
                    include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.php');                      
                }   
                else {
                    echo "PAGE NOT FOUND";
                }                   
            }       else {
                    include($pages_dir.'/home.php');
                                }

                ?>
    </div>


    <div id="main" class="main" > 


            <?php
                $pages_dir = 'pages';
            if (!empty($_GET['p2']))
                {                   
                $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
                unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);                    
                $p2 = $_GET['p2'];                      
                if (in_array($p2.'.php', $pages))
                     {
                    include($pages_dir.'/'.$p2.'.php');                     
                }   
                else {
                    echo "PAGE NOT FOUND";
                }                   
            }       else {
                    include($pages_dir.'/soon.php');
                                }

            ?>
    </div>



    <div id="rnav" class="main"> <!-- This will be the right hand side menu/navigation/advertising area -->



            <div id="top"> <h3> RIGHT NAV BAR- SHiznitz goes here innit</h3></div>  

            <div id="bottom"><h3>BOTTOM</div><h3></h3>




    </div>
    <div id="footer"> <!-- This will be the footer --><h3>FOOTER - NotFM Logo &#169; Michael Gillman. Website design &#169; Richard Ross</h3></div>  






    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XX-X to be your site's ID. 
     <script>
        (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
        function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
        e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
        e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
        r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
        ga('create','UA-XX-X');ga('send','pageview');
    </script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tested to make sure its loading, just view source, and click on the link....does it show?

Comment: check firebug for any errors !

Comment: Try adding http:// to the beggining on <script src="//ajax

Comment: No need to edit the question to mark solved. Selecting the answer which helped you is the best (and recommended) way.

Answer (score 2):

Look's like you are **testing locally.**

If that is the case

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.
```

should be

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.
```

**EDIT**

Try  setting **topwrap div** to `display:none`

Comment: Nope `//ajax` will not work if you are testing it locally .. As it cannot link to that file

Comment: i checked that url in my browser and it worked (but just in browser)

Comment: it's not looking for that file from localhost, it's looking for that file under the URL specified, using the protocol of the current request.

Comment: sry.. i meant the `local file system`

Comment: oh ok.. So is the `topwrap` div set to `display:none` in the first place.. Otherwise the slidedown will not have any effect

Comment: It wasn't, i changed it, now the topwrap div isn't there but there is no script action.

Comment: I cannot get jquery to affect any part of my code in any way.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/wUW5q/ .. Check the console for any errors and check if jQuery loads in the first place

Comment: how do i check if jquery loads?

Comment: Open developer Tools in chrome --> Click on Sources --> And check the scripts on your left.. Otherwise placing a simple alert in `DOM handler` should do

Comment: Awesome, i have it working. Developer tools in Chrome helped me find the bug. Many thanks.

Comment: Developer tools is your fried.. use it wisely :)